# Converting pandas dataframe to dict and vice versa

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df` (this is just an example)

```
col1  col2  col3
  A1    B1    C1
 NaN    B2   NaN
 NaN    B3   NaN
  A2    B4    C2
 Nan    B5    C3
  A3    B6    C4
 NaN   NaN    C5
```

The dataframe is sorted, and each `NaN` is `col1` can be thought of as a cell containing the last valid value in the column. I obtained this by using:

```
df[["col1"]] = df[["col1"]].fillna(method="ffill")
```

which gives:

```
col1  col2  col3
  A1    B1    C1
  A1    B2   NaN
  A1    B3   NaN
  A2    B4    C2
  A2    B5    C3
  A3    B6    C4
  A3   NaN    C5
```

Then, I obtain a `dict` such that its keys are the values of `col1`. These keys are associated to a dict containing the values of `col2` and `col3`:

```
data = {
    "A1": {"col2": ["B1", "B2", "B3"], "col3": ["C1"]},
    "A2": {"col2": ["B4", "B5"], "col3": ["C2", "C3"]},
    "A3": {"col2": ["B6"], "col3": ["C4", "C5"]}
}
```

I obtained `data` by doing:

```
data = {val: {"col2": group["col2"].dropna().tolist(),
              "col3": group["col3"].dropna().tolist()}
        for val, group in df.groupby("col1")}
```

This is the final result of the conversion from the dataframe `df` to the dict `data`. What I can't achieve is how to do the opposite. How can I build the very initial `df` (the one containing `NaN` values also in `col1`) if I'm given `data`? Also, feel free to help me improve the conversion from `df` to `data`.

EDIT: `df` contains `max(len(data[val]["col2"]), len(data[val]["col3"]))` rows for each `val` in `data`. If `NaN` values are required to fill the rows, they must be in the last positions. For example:

```
data = {
    "A1": {"col1": ["B1"], "col2": ["C1", "C2"]}
}
```

becomes

```
col1  col2  col3
  A1    B1    C1
  A1   NaN    C2
```

and not

```
col1  col2  col3
  A1   NaN    C1
  A1    B1    C2
```

Comment: You really can't ensure you can go back from `data` to `df` without at least some other assumptions. For instance, since you `ffill` it's impossible to tell from data whether `col1` started with `A1 NaN NaN`, `A1 A1 NaN`  or `A1 A1 A1` when you try to reverse the `ffill`

Comment: @ALollz You can actually make another assumption (I will update my question): `NaN` values are always the last values in the list. For example, for a given value of `col1`, the last values of `col2` will always be `NaN` (if there is such a value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can explode each column separately using a `cumcount` to align during the concatenate. `col1` then needs to be masked where it was duplicated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.index.name='col1'

l = []
for col in ['col2', 'col3']:
    s = df.explode(col)
    s['idx'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
    s = s.set_index('idx', append=True)
    l.append(s[col])

df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)

df = df.reset_index().drop(columns='idx')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].duplicated())
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   A1   B1   C1
1  NaN   B2  NaN
2  NaN   B3  NaN
3   A2   B4   C2
4  NaN   B5   C3
5   A3   B6   C4
6  NaN  NaN   C5
```